# degraded iops and throughput on a linux machine in a cluster

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, iops

we have a linux-based cluster on AWS with 8 workers.

OS version (taken from /proc/version) is:

Linux version 5.4.0-1029-aws (buildd@lcy01-amd64-021) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 11:09:25 UTC 2020

worker id 5 was added recently, and the problem that we see is that during times of high disk util% due to a burst of writes into the workers, the disk mounted to that worker's data dir (/dev/nvme1n1p1)
shows a degraded performance in terms of w/sec and wMB/sec, which are much lower on that worker compared to the other 7 workers (~40% less iops and throughput on that broker).

the data in this table was taken from running iostat -x on all the brokers, starting at the same time and ending after 3 hours during peak time. the cluster handles ~2M messages/sec.

another strange behavior is that broker id 7 has ~40% more iops and throughput during bursts of writes compared to the other brokers.

worker type is i3en.3xlarge with one nvme ssd 7.5TB.

**any idea as to what can cause such degraded performance in worker id 5 (or such a good performance on broker id 7)?**

this issue is causing the consumers from this cluster to lag during high writes because worker id 5 gets into high iowait, and in case some consumer reads gets into lag and performs reads from the disk then the iowait on worker id 5 climbs into ~70% and all consumers start to lag and also the producers get OOM due buffered messages that the broker doesn't accept.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the work is distribited equally? What are these workers are doing? Did you look into other load metrics? E.g. worker 5 may be just running out of memory and swapping, which would explain excessive IO.

Comment: these are kafka brokers. they receive writes from producers and reads from consumers. there are almost no reads from disk, all reads are from the page cache. worker05 isn't swapping and the process doesn't run OOM. also the worker has enough RAM to read from the page cache and not from the disk (there are less than 1MB/sec reads from disk on all workers)

Comment: Make sure that the partition is aligned with the sectors. The stats that are you showing are the similar for both nvme1n1p1 (partition) and nvme1n1 (the whole disk) ?

Comment: what do you mean by "partition is aligned with the sectors"?
and regarding the partition and disk - I use iostat and see a row per nvme1np1, how can I tell whether it's the partition or the whole disk?

Comment: The `p1` at the end refers to the partition number, so that is a partition.